# RS485 Reverse Engineering

Tags: uart, communication, rs485, logic-analyzer

I'm reversing a RS485 comunication.
I have purchased a logical analyzer for reversing and sniffing the data packets.
But i have a problem, don't knowing the exactly comunication parameters i can't "decrypt" the data passing over the bus.
How i can reverse this?

I attach a screenshot about the analysis and the used comunication parameters.

**Edit:** I know that this data segment work at 250kbps and are a segment of varius packet each constructed by 38 bytes. These bytes are some ASCII characters.

[image: The data packets]
[image: All entire packet]
[image: First configuration parameters]
[image: Second configuration parameters]

Comment: The best shot you may get answered is: add (more) waveform screen captures, please, along with expected/known message/data associated with that segment of the signal.

Comment: I know that this data segment work at 250kbps and are a segment of varius packet each constructed by 38 bytes. These bytes are some ASCII characters.

Comment: You have set the data bits to 6, but you need 7 bits for ASCII.  The most common format for UART ASCII communications is 8 bits, no parity, one stop bit.

Comment: @PeterBennett i tried in this configuration. But not resolved :(

I used the second probe for analyzing the signal and i'm starting to reading some real bytes but not resolving yet
https://imgur.com/a/1qI5HGw

Comment: Would you please tell us what are you reverse-engineering? If you know it's 250kbps, what else you do know? Also what is the logic analyzer sampling rate? I would suggest it is set much beyond 1 MHz to see anything useful. A real UART would use 4 MHz or 2 MHz to sample 250kbps signal. Also which pin are you measuring, RS485 bus directly or RX/TX data pin at transceiver?

Comment: @OscarDiManno It looks like the waveform is interpreted, it would be better to post a picture of the raw data. If you are sending ascii it shouldn't be 'low' all the time, you should see a few bits switch.

Answer (score 0):

The second waveform is a packet (?), then, assuming it is common UART serial data format, and assuming it has protocols in good shape:
The very beginning of the packet has "flag" and "headers". In the middle somewhere has "payload". If the data are for sure ASCII; capture a few, expand the timing, find the patterns of '0' or '1' appearing at either the b[0] or b[7] (since it likely is 8 bits data stream). ASCII data is loaded in 7 bits, so the MSB likely be the same, unless it does "don't care". Start/stop bits can be resolved by a similar analisys. Please do the capture, and post.